# MySQL: Select number of users with specific number of contest entries

Tags: mysql

I have these three (simplified) tables for a contest application:

```
**user**
user_id    

**contest**
contest_id

**contest_entry**
contest_id
user_id
```

There are several contests, and each user can enter each contest once (creating a contest_entry record).

Thus far there have been 5 contests, so I'd like to get a count of how many users have entered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 contests. An example of the format I'm looking for is this:

```
num_contests_entered      num_users
0                         102
1                         87
2                         345
3                         254
4                         567
5                         489
```

I am completely stumped on the SQL needed to achieve this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Best,
Chris

**EDIT**: To clarify, an example of what I am looking for is

```
102 users entered 0 contests
87 users entered 1 contest
345 users entered 2 contests
```

etc..

Comment: @njk you're right. uhmm Chris, what is 0,1,2,3,4, and 5?

Comment: Amended the question, I think it was a little ambiguous!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT num_contests_entered,
       COUNT(1) num_users
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(ce.contest_id) num_contests_entered
           FROM user u
           LEFT
          OUTER
           JOIN contest_entry ce
             ON ce.user_id = u.user_id
          GROUP
             BY u.user_id
       ) t
 GROUP
    BY num_contests_entered
 ORDER
    BY num_contests_entered
;
```

The subquery finds, for each user, how many contests they entered; the outer query groups users by that count, thereby determining the number of users that entered that many contests.

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: @njk well, your fiddle shows that it works! The only missing part (as for my answer) are the lines where there are no user with a given participations number (1 and 3 in your case).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks very much! I will now dissect it and learn a thing or two :)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I am dyslexic at times.